# find the volume of the solid when the region under the curve $y=x\sqrt{4-x^2}$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$ is rotated about the $y$-axis

Tags: calculus

I tried:
$$y = x\sqrt{4-x^2}$$
When the curve is rotated from $x = 0$ to $x = 2$, the radius of the curve obtained is:
$$A = \pi \ r^2 = \pi(x\sqrt{4-x^2})^2 = \pi(x^2(4-x^2)) = \pi(4x^2-x^4)$$
So, the volume is:
$$V = \pi\int_0^2(4x^2-x^4)dx = \pi\frac{64}{15} = 13.4$$

When I put the answer in webwork, it said it was wrong.

Comment: You have the correct answer for rotation  about the $x$-axis.  For about the $y$-axis, method of cylindrical shells may be best.

Comment: You were right. I got it, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. A best possible outcome, you solved the problem yourself.

Comment: This answer seems to be integrating $y^2$ not $r^2$! If you are rotating about the $y$ axis then $r=x$ not $y$, so you need to integrate $\pi \int x^2 y$ from 0 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

The curve has maximum value at $ (\sqrt2,2) $. So need to only cover volume of external shells as the inside shells overlap, they should be excluded.

$$ V = \int_{\sqrt2}^2 \pi x^2 \frac{dy}{dx} dx $$

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the question is very odd, since it says the volume about the $y$ axis but that is the integral of $y^2$, which would be correct if we were rotating about the $x$ axis. For rotating about the $y$ axis, we get the volume V by integrating shells of $\pi x^2y$ from 0 to 2, so we need
$$
V=\pi\int_0^2 x^3 \sqrt{4-x^2} dx
$$
This integral may be performed by substituting $u=x^2$, $du=2x dx$ to give
$$
\frac12\int_0^4 u \sqrt{4-u} du
$$
then substituting $s=4-u$ to give
$$
\frac12\int_0^44s^{1/2}-s^{3/2} ds=
\frac12\left\{4\times\frac23s^{3/2}-\frac25s^{5/2}\right\}\Biggr|_0^4={64\over 15}
$$

Comment: Using the shell method $V = \int_{a}^{b} 2\pi xf(x)~dx$, I obtain $V = 2\pi\int_{0}^{2} x^2\sqrt{4 - x^2} = 2\pi^2$.